# A setOnClickListener inside another doesn't work

Tags: android

This setOnClickListener doesn't work. I have a Image Button that open a custom Tooltip, whit a layout, where I have three Text View. I want add an event when I click on a TextView, but it doesn't work. Any solution?
This is the code:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="135dp"
android:layout_height="120dp"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="@drawable/nav_up"
android:id="@+id/tooltip_menu_id">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tooltip_profile"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/menu_item_profile"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/secondary_grey"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tooltip_notifications"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/menu_item_notifications"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        />

    <View
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/secondary_grey"
        android:layout_gravity="right"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tooltip_logout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:text="@string/menu_item_logout"
        android:textColor="@color/black"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        />
```

And java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

TooltipWindow tooltipWindow;

TextView btnLogout;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    final TextView usernameUser = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.username_user);

    final ImageButton btnMenuUser = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btn_user_menu);


tooltipWindow = new TooltipWindow(this);

    btnMenuUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            tooltipWindow.showToolTip(view, Gravity.RIGHT);

    }
    });

View myView = findViewById(R.id.tooltip_menu_id);

    btnLogout = myView.findViewById(R.id.tooltip_logout);

    btnLogout.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intentLogout = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intentLogout);
            finish();

        }
    });

}



}
```

When I click on btnLogout doesn't work. I do not know if the problem could be that btnLogout is inside a layout that opens with another setOnClickListener, which conflicts the second onClick

Comment: Post your complete java code

Comment: is here that I act on the event, which other part of the code is needed?

Comment: post the full code of your activity

Comment: the above code not have any problem...maybe you have problem somewhere else..post complete activity code so community can help you

Comment: I modified the code. as I wrote, the problem could be that the two onClick are in conflict? how do I say to the first on click that if clicked leaves the listening to the second?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing `clickable` attribute on your `tooltip_logout` `TextView`.

Add the following : `android:clickable="true"`

Your `TextView` will then be :

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tooltip_logout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:text="@string/menu_item_logout"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:textSize="15dp"
    android:clickable="true" />
```

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED**

Your "myView" is playing the role of "menu", so the proper way to do is creating a menu resource file. Here is the example.

**test_menu.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_profile" android:title="profile" app:showAsAction="always"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_notification" android:title="notification" app:showAsAction="always"></item>
    <item android:id="@+id/menu_item_logout" android:title="logout" app:showAsAction="always"></item>
</menu>
```

Overwrite `onCreateOptionsMenu` to inflate custom menu, and use `onOptionsItemSelected` to do your work.

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        setTitle("");
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.test_menu, menu);

        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menu_item_logout:
                Toast.makeText(this, "your work", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                break;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

[Look something like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nw7AY.png)

Comment: I also tried this but I get the following error:
Could not find method onClick(View) in a parent or ancestor Context for android:onClick attribute defined on view class android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView with id 'tooltip_logout'

Comment: Then I think that you need to inflate "myView" because you are now under "activity_main.xml", while you want the reference of other view called "tooltip_menu_id".

Comment: I also thought about this ... could you tell me where to inflate "myView" on my code?

Comment: I thank you for making an example of how to do .. just that what I have to get unfortunately is this:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DaOWd.png

that's why I did not use an optionMenu ... how could I do this?